# Using Viola with jupyter notebook on Binder gives error

Tags: jupyter-notebook, voila

I am doing the fast.ai v2 course on deep learning and on deploying my first app (as suggested in chapter 2 of the [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08C2KM7NR), I am using viola on top of the jupyter notebook to make it run without showing the cells, therefore act as an app. When I run it on binder it gives the following error.

[image]

The related github (therefore the codes) is [here](https://github.com/Babakjfard/event_detector) and you can open the binder by clicking the logo in the readme. I would be grateful for your help

Comment: Did u try updating fastai version? Try adding "fastai" in requirement.txt file instead of "fastai>=2". It worked for me.